# Directing Xorg input to selected application

Tags: linux, xorg, input

I'm trying to play Frets on Fire using my PS3 Guitar Hero III controller. It works right away, but it's also controlling the cursor as if it's a mouse. I'd like to play the game windowed, but that's impossible because the controller would move the cursor and unfocus the game window.

One idea I had is to direct the input to one application only, so only the game window will accept input from the guitar. I could not find such an option so far. But I'm not very familiar with Xorg, so I might have missed something.

If there's such an option, or if someone comes up with a better idea, it would be of great help to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add an `InputDevice` section to your Xorg configuration that sets the `SendCoreEvents` option for the device to `false`. See the `xorg.conf(5)` man page for more details.

Comment: Ended up using `InputClass`, because I can't understand how to assign an `InpuDevice` to a specific device, and the `Floating` option, since `SendCoreEvents` is deprecated in the Xorg version I'm using. It worked. Thank you for the pointers!